# json encoding not working in mysql fetch array

Tags: php

```
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysql_query("select `menu_item_name` from menu_option"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['menu_item_name'];


    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

From
`array_push($return_arr,$row_array);`
To
`$return_arr = array_push($return_arr,$row_array);`

Comment: the problem is solved json encode only utf-8 charset its not encoding latin_utf_cli

Answer (score 0):

Run your SQL first and ensure that what you're getting back is in fact a result.

This can be done by either running

`select menu_item_name from menu_option`

manually in mysql shell or through something like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Also, a `print_r($return_arr)` won't hurt to debug the issue you're having as the code itself should work fine. JSON_ENCODE works. The problem you're having is that you don't have an array.

Side note: It's better to use some form of ORM instead of writing low-level SQL for yourself. Have a look into [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Redbean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/), and save yourself some headaches.